# Create static resource from Managed Package PostInstall script

Tags: apex, managed-package, metadata-api, postinstall

I'm trying to create static resource json file (with metadata api) on after install script, that runs after Managed Package is installed.
The issues I faced so far are:

- one can't run metadata api callouts directly from afterinstall script (future method seems to be the way to go).
- there's no session ID in postinstall context

Taking that into account, is it even possible to create a static resource from after install script?

Comment: Any specific reason to create static resource? Why not include it in the package it self.

Comment: Static resource included in the package can't be modified later, and that's one of the app's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with creating `Post Install Instructions` page, that registers remote site setting for metadata API and then creates the Static Resource. Of course one could also redirect to the same page from the app tab. I don't think there's any better way to achieve that for now.